# Applying conditions to python lists

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have a text file which has two columns. Let's call them `r and xi` and I load them using `r,xi = numpy.loadtext`

```
 r         xi
2.5      2.510891
7.5     -0.436541
12.5     0.576983
17.5     0.377067
22.5     0.19648
27.5    -0.003876
32.5     0.117554
37.5     0.136895
42.5     0.261832
47.5    -0.08984
```

I know how to *remove all the negative values in `xi`*. I use `xi = [i for i in xi if i>0]` which gives me all the positive values.

*How can I now remove the corresponding `r` values?*

Here in the above example, the second row of r and xi should be removed as `xi = -0.4` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note: even thought the question refers to python "lists", since the command used to read in the objects is `numpy.loadtxt`, we actually have numpy array objects, so let's take advantage of that.]

Instead of using a list comprehension, you can make a boolean array and use that to index.  You should read the section of the tutorial on ["advanced indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).  For example:

```
>>> r, xi = np.loadtxt("s.dat", skiprows=1, unpack=True)
>>> keep = xi > 0
>>> keep
array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

This array has True where `xi > 0` and False where it's not.  We can now use `keep` to select the ones we want:

```
>>> r[keep]
array([  2.5,  12.5,  17.5,  22.5,  32.5,  37.5,  42.5])
>>> xi[keep]
array([ 2.510891,  0.576983,  0.377067,  0.19648 ,  0.117554,  0.136895,
        0.261832])
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a very similar list comprehension to what you have now:

```
comp_list = [(r_i, xi_i) for r_i, xi_i in zip(r, xi) if xi_i > 0]
```

This will give you a list of tuples, which you can then separate out fairly easily

**Demo:**

```
>>> r = [2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5]
>>> xi = [2.51, -0.43, 0.57, 0.37, 0.19, -0.003]
>>> comp_list = [(r_i, xi_i) for r_i, xi_i in zip(r, xi) if xi_i > 0]
>>> comp_list
[(2.5, 2.51), (12.5, 0.57), (17.5, 0.37), (22.5, 0.19)]
>>> r, xi = zip(*comp_list)
>>> r
(2.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5)
>>> xi
(2.51, 0.57, 0.37, 0.19)
```

Or if you're one of those folks who likes to do it all in one go:

```
r, xi = zip(*[(r_i, xi_i) for r_i, xi_i in zip(r, xi) if xi_i > 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to filter lines before split them on 2 lists?

```
source_lines = numpy.loadtext(f)
filtered_lines = [x for x in source_lines if x[1] > 0]
```